# exec function. Is there a way to back to the main program?

Tags: c, linux, exec

I've a problem with exec() function under ubuntu.
Is there any possibility to go back to the main program?

example:

```
printf("Some instructions at beginning\n");
execlp("ls","ls", "-l", NULL);

// i want to continue this program after exec and see the text below
printf("Other instructions\n");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  A successful `exec` call *replaces* the current program with another program.  If you want both the parent and child to stick around, you need to call [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) before `exec`:

```
pid_t childpid = fork();
if(childpid < 0)
{
    // Handle error
}
else if(childpid == 0)
{
    // We are the child
    exec(...);
}
else
{
    // We are the parent: interact with the child, wait for it, etc.
}
```

Note that a failed `exec` call (e.g. the given executable doesn't exist) does return.  If `exec` returns, it's always because of an error, so be prepared to handle the error.

Comment: So exec wont terminate main program if I put him in child?

Comment: @user1850043 yes. It will replace the child-process's image, leaving the parent intact.

Answer (score 3):

`exec` replaces the executable file image. There is no way back. A nice alternative is `vfork() exec`. `vfork` copies the process, continues in the copy and when it completes its execution, continues the main process. The copy can `exec` the desired file. Example:

```
printf("Some instructions at beginning\n");
if(!vfork()){
    // child
    execlp("ls","ls", "-l", NULL); // child is replaced
}
// parent continues after child is gone
printf("Other instructions\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

**No, Not possible using exec family functions** because the executable file, which is generated from your previous code i.e. code which contains ***execlp("ls","ls","-l",NULL)***  function, is replaced by the executable file you are going to run by ***execlp()*** function i.e. **ls**. 
So when this function is executed successfully, you no more have that old executable file containing ***execlp()*** function.

Use **system("ls -l");**  function if you want to run any other process and want to return to current process.

Answer (score 1):

**[`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)** *replaces* the current process image with a new process image, so, **no**, that wouldn't be possible.

If you want to get back to what you were doing previously, you could do a fork and call an exec from the child process.

```
if (fork() == 0){ //this part will only be executed by the child process
        execlp("ls","ls", "-l", NULL);
        wait((int*)0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. The `exec` family of functions **replaces** the current process with a new process image. If you don't want to do that, you need to `fork` before calling `exec`, so that the newly forked copy of your process gets replaced (instead of the original getting replaced).

Answer (score 1):

Actually `exec()` or it's family of functions replace the current process and executes

So try fork and use `exec()` in child process, and wait in parent till child terminates.

Like this :

```
if(!fork())
 {
  // In child
  execlp("ls","ls","-l",NULL);
 }
 wait(NULL);
  // In parent 
 //rest of code
```